# DatePeriod in php >5.3.0 and <5.3.3

Tags: php, date, php-5.3, period

Can I reset period object in php <=5.3.3?
I would like to use same period object some times in foreach

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2013-10-01');
$end = new DateTime('2013-10-02');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach ($period as $p) {
    var_dump($p);
}

reset($period);

foreach ($period as $p) {
    var_dump($p);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/sKOVp)

Comment: The Demo should not be in the question since it provides the answer

Comment: @Brewal Not really - If you look at the question (and not just the title which has a `>` instead of a `<`) then you'll see that the output for 5.3.0 - 5.3.3 is different than 5.3.4+. OP asks what to do in 5.3.0 - 5.3.3.

Comment: well, the ideal solution is to upgrade. The reason 5.3.4 exists is to fix issues that were in 5.3.3. The same applies with all subsequent versions through to 5.3.27. If you're still on 5.3.3, then you're a long way behind on your updates.

Comment: @Spudley Not always we have control about production server ;) I need solution to work with any 5.3 version.. So Glavic's solution is well for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function **[`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php)**<sup>PHP >= 5.1.0</sup>, that copies elements of an iterator to array. Then you can use this array multiple times.

```php
// ...
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
$periods = iterator_to_array($period);
// ...
```

**[Demo](http://3v4l.org/j4Wsp)**